# How to find a prefab by name

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a problem, I need to block the creation of a new object (prefab) if there is already one prefab on the stage.I solved it with GameObject.FindWithTag, but maybe there is some other way

```
using UnityEngine;

public class CreateBullet : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform firePoint;
public GameObject ballPrefab;

    void Update()
    {
        if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
        {
            if (GameObject.FindWithTag("ballBullet") == null)
            {
                CreatingBulletBall();
            }
        }
    }

    void CreatingBulletBall()
    {
        Instantiate(ballPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
    }

}
```

Comment: Set a bool on assignment or reference the assigned object in the script. Then you can check against the bool or whether the reference is null. No need to find the prefab I think, if I understand you correctly (not sure what you mean with on the stage).

Comment: There is a ball player on the scene, when a key is pressed a bullet is created (the prefab is also a ball). When the key is released the bullet flies forward and is destroyed by another object. It is necessary to block the creation of the next bullet until the first one is destroyed

Comment: Hold a reference to the created object and when it is destroyed, set the reference to null. Only instantiate when the variable is null?

Answer (score 0):

Here is what you should do:

1. Create script `Bullet.cs` with code from below;
2. Add it as component to the bullet prefab;
3. Change the `CreateBullet` class as shown below;
4. Assign bullet prefab to the `ballPrefab` field of the `CreateBullet` component (if unassigned after script change).

How it works: if `_bullet` field is null, new bullet is created and stored there. When bullet is destroyed, it fires event `Destroyed`. Callback `OnBulletDestroyed` will assign null to `_bullet`, so it can be created again.

File `CreateBullet.cs`:

```
    public class CreateBullet : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform firePoint;
        public Bullet ballPrefab;
    
        private void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                TryCreateBulletBall();
        }
    
        private Bullet? _bullet = null;
    
        private void TryCreateBulletBall()
        {
            if (this._bullet != null)
                return;
            this._bullet = Instantiate(ballPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
            this._bullet.Destroyed += this.OnBulletDestroyed;
        }
    
        private void OnBulletDestroyed()
        {
            this._bullet.Destroyed -= this.OnBulletDestroyed;
            this._bullet = null;
        }
    }
```

File `Bullet.cs`:

```
    public class Bullet : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public event Action? Destroyed;
    
        private void OnDestroy()
        {
            this.Destroyed?.Invoke();
        }
    }
```

<s>Not tested, but it should work.</s> It works.

**Update:**

**About performance:**

In terms of performance it's perfectly fine. It is idiomatic to store the reference to the object once (through Inspector, in `Start`/`Awake` hooks, when object is instantiated, etc), instead of calling any of `Find...()` or `GetComponent()` methods in the `Update` hook. In fact, [docs for `Find()` method](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject.Find.html#:%7E:text=a%20path%20name.-,For%20performance%20reasons%2C%20it%20is%20recommended%20to%20not%20use%20this%20function%20every%20frame.,-Instead%2C%20cache%20the) state that you should avoid calling it every frame.

**Simplified version of code.**
As @derHugo noted in comment, it's sufficient to have this code only:

File `CreateBullet.cs`:

```
    public class CreateBullet : MonoBehaviour
    {
        public Transform firePoint;
        public GameObject ballPrefab;
    
        private void Update()
        {
            if (Input.GetMouseButtonDown(0))
                TryCreateBulletBall();
        }
    
        private GameObject _bullet;
    
        private void TryCreateBulletBall()
        {
            if (this._bullet)
                return;
            this._bullet = Instantiate(ballPrefab, firePoint.position, firePoint.rotation);
        }
    }
```

Comment: it works great, thank you very much. But I'm wondering how your solution is better in optimization

Comment: The destroyed and nullable is redundant. `UnityEngine.Object` has a custom `==` implementation so that if an object has been destroyed it already behaves correctly for `this._bullet != null` .. in general it is recommended to rather use the bool operator and `if(_bullet)` though .. this one definitely also behaves correctly if the bullet was destroyed in the same frame

Comment: @derHugo, do you mean in the last sentence, that if I implement your approach without `Bullet` class and `OnBulletDestroyed` callback, the condition `_bullet != null` will be `false` until next frame? And in my approach it will be `true` in the same frame as the object destroyed? Isn't `OnDestroy` hook called after `Update`?

Comment: what I mean is .. just use `Bullet _bullet;` and `if(_bullet) return;` .. that already covers it without the need for any callbacks